# Do Ability Score Limits permanently change from features that change it?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores

In D&D 5E, there are multiple different ways to increase ones Ability Score permanently, for example, like the *Ability Score Increase* and *Primal Champion (Barbarian Capstone)* class features, or the various manuals/tomes magic items (e.g. *Manual of Gainful Exercise*). For the examples provided, all of these methods specify the maximum limit for which an Ability Score can reach:

- *Ability Score Increase* increases an Ability Score by 2 up to a limit of **20**
- *Primal Champion* increases Strength/Constitution by 4 up to a limit of **24**
- *Manual of Gainful Exercise* increases Strength by 2 and the limit by **2**

For a hypothetical scenario, I'm playing a Barbarian with 18 Strength, and my character reads the *Manual of Gainful Exercise* which increases my Strength to 20. Am I able to increase my Strength beyond 20 **from** an *Ability Score Increase* due to the *Manual of Gainful Exercise* increasing my Ability Score limit by 2, or does the *Ability Score Increase* feature override this limit to be 20, thus not being able to increase my Strength in this matter?

Comment: @Medix2 Yeah link answers my question. Serves me right for not looking hard enough. Can be closed.

Comment: It's still helpful to have a duplicate for search results purposes

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.